# Iterating Through An Object In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

If I have an object, like so:

```
const test = [
  { x: 'A', y:'1' },
  { x: 'A', y:'2' },
  { x: 'B', y:'1' },
  { x: 'A', y:'3' },
  { x: 'C', y:'1' },
];
```

How can I go through it, and find the in order sequence `[A, B, C]` from x, where `[A, B, C]` belongs to a unique y?

So far I tried iterating through the object using a for loop, finding all 'A', 'B', 'C', in order, but I cannot ensure that they all belong to the same y item.

Comment: Remember add `=` after `const test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the array into an object of arrays corresponding to only one particular `y` first:

```js
const test = [
  { x: 'A', y:'1' },
  { x: 'A', y:'2' },
  { x: 'B', y:'1' },
  { x: 'A', y:'3' },
  { x: 'C', y:'1' },
];
const reducedToYs = test.reduce((accum, { x, y }) => {
  accum[y] = (accum[y] || '') + x;
  return accum;
}, {});
const found = Object.entries(reducedToYs)
  .find(([y, str]) => str.includes('ABC'));
console.log('y: ' + found[0] + ', entire string: ' + found[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I should learn how to use these properly. Just curious, was this something that was possible with a for loop? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, you can do anything with a `for` loop - which is exactly the problem with `for` loops IMO. Using the array methods instead offers better abstraction, does not require manual iteration, and gives a clearer picture of what the function is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes the target Y value. Loop through the test array and compare the y value to your target value and if it matches - push the x value into an array. Then return that array.

If a string is required ("ABC)" then rather than creating an array  create a string and append the x value to it to build the string that is then returned.

```js
const test = [
  { x: 'A', y:'1' },
  { x: 'A', y:'2' },
  { x: 'B', y:'1' },
  { x: 'A', y:'3' },
  { x: 'C', y:'1' },
];



function testValue(str) {
    let xArray = [];
    test.forEach(function(item) { 
      if(item['y'] === str) {xArray.push(item['x'])}
   })
  return xArray;
  }
  
console.log(testValue('1')) // gives ["A", "B", "C"]
```